# Restore Android Samsung Galaxy S Captivate SGH-I896 back to original installation

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-captivate

I have a Android Samsung Galaxy S Captivate SGH-I896 and I have some problems with the sound. My provider sent me a new one and expect the old one back in it's original state.

So I have one that is rooted and unlocked and a clean one.

Can someone help me unroot it knowing I already did a factory reset on it.

I'm trying to root it again (thinking the unroot will work) and I'm trying the same way I did it the first time but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to format the old one with some image made from the new one?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use Kies to update your old one (or use Odin/Heimdall to install some firmware from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/?page=3)). Afaik the Galaxy S (Captivate) does not have a custom rom flash counter (that was introduced with the S2 to see if one had installed custom roms before, so you don't have to apply 'Triangle Away' to reset it before sending back your old phone)

You basically have 2 options for your new one:

- Root the standard firmware using [CF-Root by Chainfire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=788108)
- Install an aftermarket firmware like CyanogenMod (ICS already available, JB also)

To install CyanogenMod-9 (an Android-4.0/Ice-Cream-Sandwich based custom rom), here are some infos:
Here's their [Wiki FAQ for your phone](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_FAQ) and here's the [full update guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Captivate%3a_Full_Update_Guide), here are [downloads for the Captivate](http://get.cm/?device=captivatemtd)